# Imaging floating when resizing browser window

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

been trying to get my logo which is a .gif to float on my header image and stick there even when resizing page 
almost had it, then i resized my window. Am i wasting my time because i actually give up been trying for hours with no luck.

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <title>B.13 DJ Hire</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
            href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.0r4/build/reset/reset-min.css">

                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="bubba.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>

     <div id="box">
     <div id="header">
    <a href="index.html" class="banner">
         <img src="images/banner.jpg">
      </a>

      <a href="index.html" class="logo">
         <img src="images/logo.gif">
      </a>



</div>
     <h1>B13. DJ Equipment Hire</h1>
     <nav>
        <ul id="mainnav">
            <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="mixers"><a href="mixers.html">Mixers</a></li>
            <li class="turntables"><a href="turntables.html">Turntables</a></li>
            <li class="mp3"><a href="mp3.html">MP3 Media Players</a></li>
            <li class="headphones"><a href="headphones.html">Headphones</a></li>
            <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <h2> Our Equipment Range<h2>
         <br><br>
<p> we are a equipment hire company..</p>



      <br>

     <p id="footer">45 Marsh Grass Ln. &#8226; Marble, MN 55764 &#8226; (218) 555-5253</p>
     </div>
     </body>
```

Here is my CSS code

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
h1, h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:  georgia, "times new roman", times, serif;
    }
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
    background: #585858;
    line-height: 1.90em;
    width: auto;
    text-align: centre;
    background-position: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    border-radius: 0.30em;
    }

h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;

    }

#box {
    border-style: none;
    width: 70em;
    padding: 0em;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #C2C2C2;
    }

#header{

    }

.banner img{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height:206px;
    width:1120px;
    z-index: 1;
    display:block;
    }

.logo img  {
    position: absolute;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    z-index: 2; 
    height:290px;
    width:712px;
    bottom:335px;
    right:50px;

    }
#footer {
    background: #A6A6A6;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0.25em;
    margin: 0;
    }

.callout {
    font-weight: bold;  
    }

#mainnav {
    text-align: center;
    background: #A6A6A6;
    padding: 0.75em;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    }

#mainnav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: A6A6A6;
  color: #A6A6A6;
  }

#mainnav a:link{
    color:black;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

#mainnav a:hover{
    color: blue;
    background-color:#C2C2C2;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-shadow: 8px 12px 12px blue;
    }

#mainnav a:visited {
    color: black;
    }

#mainnav li.home a{
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #A6A6A6;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #A6A6A6;
    }

#mainnav li.home a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color:#C2C2C2;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    }

#mainnav li.mixers a{
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #A6A6A6;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #A6A6A6;
    }

#mainnav li.mixers a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color:#C2C2C2;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    }

#mainnav li.turntables a{
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #A6A6A6;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #A6A6A6;
    }

#mainnav li.turntables a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color:#C2C2C2 ;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    }

#mainnav li.mp3 a{
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #A6A6A6;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #A6A6A6;
    }

#mainnav li.mp3 a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color:#C2C2C2 ;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    }

#mainnav li.headphones a{
    color:#black;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #A6A6A6;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #A6A6A6;
    }

#mainnav li.headphones a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color:#C2C2C2 ;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    }

#mainnav li.contact a{
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #A6A6A6;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #A6A6A6;
    }

#mainnav li.contact a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color:#C2C2C2 ;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    }

#slideshow {
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    }

#pics {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    }

    #content {
    position: relative;
}
#content img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    }


img {
    max-width: 120%;
    display: block;
    background-size: 100%;

}


img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#slideshow {
wd
```

Comment: You mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/3L29qv5q/1/

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to float your image, and you have `float` stated for the logo style, but you also have `position:absolute` stated as well. You need to use one or the other to achieve your goal my friend.

Also you are missing a few closing DIVs in your code. Can you share a URL to your issue? that may be easier than seeing the incomplete code.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS styling you have (position:absolute) is causing the problem. Along with the fact that you have it positioned exactly in a fixed spot on the page with your position properties like "top" "bottom" "left" and "right". You do not want this when you have a logo in a spot on the page that doesn't move around (like in your header). To fix this, you want to remove what you had under the CSS for ".logo img" and put the following:

```
.logo img  {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
```

Here is an example of it: https://jsfiddle.net/Lp7fwm7a/. When you resize the window, the logo stays in the correct place like how you want it.

You might also want to look into the float property if you have two div's in your header. Here's a good article on it: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/.

Answer (score 0):

Using the position: absolute; attribute means that image is being positioned according to the browser window (because you don't have any other absolute positioned elements on the page).

Your top and bottom values are counting from the edge of the browser window, not from the edge of your image.

---

You can center it like by replacing **.logo img** with:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto 0;
height: 290px;
width: 712px;
z-index: 2;
```

Your logo is a lot taller than your header image.  I noticed the top of the logo in your code was cut off, not sure if you meant to do that or not but if you edit that first 0 in margin, you can adjust the top margin. -100px or so should put it back where you had it.

---

Also just a comment about what the other answers say, you're not missing a closing div tag - there's just really inconsistent indentation making your HTML and CSS really difficult to read.  You are missing a / in the closing h2 tag and you spelled 'center' as 'centre' in your h1, h2 CSS.

Here's a link to all the fixes (including indentation): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpXKVG

Comment: sorry i am new to html, and i should take more care in my work

Comment: Don't worry about it, it was just a general comment. Are you using a text editor? The syntax highlighting should really help.  Plus most editors have hotkeys that will write your closing tags for you as you go.

And... how did my example go? Did it work for you?

Comment: using notepad++ , your example went fine catherine, the logo finally sticks how i wanted it to, for me java is easier than html code

Comment: Ah, yeah, it can be a little disorienting.  Glad it worked - don't forget to mark the question answered! ;)